# Add a click function dynamically within a for loop using closure

Tags: for-loop, click, closures, jquery

I am trying to create a dynamic accordion.  My problem is that I can not seem to get a reference to the `i` variable inside the for loop.  I know it is a scope problem but I thought this closure would do the trick.... Please someone help me out as this is driving me completely insane.

```
jQuery(function(){

  var tables = jQuery('table');
  var tableHeadings = jQuery('h3');

  for(i =0 , ii = tableHeadings.length; i < ii; i++){
     (function(){ 

        var index = i;
        tables.eq(index).addClass('table-' + index);

        tableHeadings.eq(index).click(function(){   
            tables.eq(index).slideToggle(); 
        });

      })();
    }  
});
```

Comment: Have you got a live example of where this fails? This should work AFAIK.

Comment: Why would you need a closure here? Just execute the code in the for loop directly.

Comment: @asawyer: Because otherwise in the click handler, `i` (or `index`) would always be the last value.

Comment: @Matt Ah I see. Why not `$("h3").each(function(i,e){ ... });` then, instead of the awkward for loop?

Comment: @asawyer: That'd work as well, have to ask `@RobertRubyII why he elected not to use it :).

Comment: If you post the html we might be able to suggest slightly better code for doing this

Comment: ever do something and then look at and be like huh I thought I didn't understand that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better yet:

```
tableHeadings.each(function(index, element) {
  tables.eq(index).addClass('table-' + index);

  tableHeadings.eq(index).click(function() {   
    tables.eq(index).slideToggle(); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Dunno if it is better to use `tableHeadings.eq(index)` or `$(this)`

Comment: good point.  I just copy-pasted the body, but you're right.  This is a less straightforward case because of the need to correlate `tables` and `tableHeadings` - I would probably refactor the DOM to keep those together, perhaps wrap in a DIV and then use the wrapper as the selector and loop var instead.